# Executing Fortify commands with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, fortify

I am trying to run Fortify commands through a batch file. Typically when running a fortify scan I use these three different commands via command line:

```
sourceanalyzer -b buildId-clean

sourceanalyzer -b buildId devenv "mysolution.sln" /Rebuild Debug 

sourceanalyzer -b buildId -scan -f "mysolution.fpr" -format fpr
```

Now when running the second command you need devenv to complete the translation.  What is the best approach to call this?  I've tried to run the `VsDevCmd.bat` before running the commands in a batch file, but end up with this:

```
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
```

This is even having the `.bat` file in the same directory I am call the fortify batch file.

I've also called devenv.com but get this error:

> [error]: The HPE Security Fortify add-in for Visual Studio did not
>   execute; ther efore, no files were translated. Ensure that the HPE
>   Security Fortify add-in is installed. If you are running Visual Studio
>   2005 SP1, you must also install t he hotfix indicated by KB934517.

Here is the batch file command:

```
set SOURCEANALYZER=sourceanalyzer
set BUILDID="buildId"
set DEVCOMMAND="devenv.com"
set SOLUTIONFILE="mysolution.sln"
set ARGS="/Rebuild Debug"

%SOURCEANALYZER% -b %BUILDID% %DEVCOMMAND% %MYSOLUTION% %ARGS%
```

My `VsDevCmd.bat` and `devenv.com` comes from **VS2015** directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have three options for the `devenv` argument when running through command line:

1. Use the fully-qualified path to the `devenv.exe` file, usually located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mircosoft Visual Studio x.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`
2. From a regular command line window, call `vsvars32.bat` before running the `sourceanalyzer` command to set some local variables, such as `devenv`, to the proper paths. This file is located at `‪C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio x.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat`.
3. Run the `sourceanalyzer` command via the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt. This is the same as opening a traditional command line window and executing `vsvars32.bat`.

If you do option 2 or 3, you will be able to simply use the variable `devenv` in the `sourceanalyzer` command, while option 1 will require a hard path in the command, but could be useful if you need to specify a version of Visual Studio to build with.